# подключить кассу к сайту на Google Sites

Tags: php

Какую можно подключить кассу на  Google Sites? Интернет-магазин создан на Google Sites, нужно подключить к нему кассу.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Интернет-магазин создан на Google Sites. Нужно подключить кассу

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что интернет магазин на Google Sites хорошая идея)

Comment: Это да, его не я делала.  Мне нужно подключить кассу.. В комментах на ютубе нашла, что его можно к Робокассе подключить, но может быть есть еще какие-то варианты..